# Query to insert and relate 2 ID's (primary keys) of entities in the third table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many

I am working on Hibernate many to many relationship.

As I don't have enough reputations I am unable to add Image but you can find the image in [this](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/) Link.

Now, I have some data in both the tables: Student and Course. I have selected a Student and selected few courses(using checkbox in UI). I need to save 1 StudentID and few CourseIDs in the third table StudentCourseEnrollment.

Can any one help me out in this to write a query, with an example Link or a sample piece of code.

### `Course Class`

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "course")  
 private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<Student>();
```

### `Student Class`

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "student")  
 private Set<Course> course = new HashSet<Course>();
```

### `Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "selectCourse.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)

       public @ResponseBody String selCourses(@RequestParam("studentId") String studentId, @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model,HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("selectedIDS") List<String> courseIds) {
    System.out.println("testing "+ courseIds.toString());
        studentId=request.getParameter("studentId");

      serviceInterface.method();  

        return "";
    }
```

Here, I am able to get all the required Id's. Only thing is Query Implementation for that method to save these Ids.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need any query. All you need is adding the courses the the list of courses of the student (and/or vice-versa). Post your code.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added my code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Your mapping makes no sense. The student.courses field is mapped as the inverse of the course.students one, which is also mapped as the inverse of student.courses. One side must have the mappedBy attribute, the other must not.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply. I am trying to add courses to a Student and then retrieving the students based on a course.

Comment: I understand that. But that doesn't make the mapping more correct.

Comment: @JBNizet Do you have any examples online?

Comment: How about... the official documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5517

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the mapping. Can you please suggest an example for query part.

Comment: I told you already. You don't need a query. All you need is to add a course to the set of student's courses.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok Thanks, but will that add relationship in the third table is my question.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet I have tried with the example, I am getting this error.  HTTP Status 500 - Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.axiscapstone.tender.domain.Vendor]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: You probably forgot to annotate a field of type Vendor with OneToOne or ManyToOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by using OneTOMany bidirectional for Student and Course, then created a third Entity Student_Course.